# $\neg \neg A \supset A$ in intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

I read that the formula $\neg \neg A \supset A$ is not intuitionistically valid. Why is that? If someone can explain me I would be glad.

Comment: Blog post about this:L http://blog.plover.com/math/IL-contradiction.html

Comment: The *intuitionsitic* rejection of $\lnot \lnot A \supset A$ is due to its equivalence with *LEM* : $\lnot A \lor A$, that is "unsound" for [Intuitionsitic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that : $\lnot \lnot A \supset A$ is : $((A \supset \bot) \supset \bot) \supset A$.

According to the [BHK-interpretation](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionistic-logic-development/#1.1), a proof of $A \supset \bot$ is a *procedure* $\gamma_0$ that transform a proof of $A$ into a proof of $\bot$.

A proof of $(A \supset \bot) \supset \bot$ is a procedure $\gamma_1$ that, when "applied" to $\gamma_0$, extract a proof of $\bot$.

Thus, a proof of $((A \supset \bot) \supset \bot)$ must be a procedure $\gamma_2$ that, when "applied" to $\gamma_1$, extract a proof of $A$.

But then, having extracted it, we can use it with $\gamma_0$ to get a proof of $\bot$, and this is impossible : the *calculus* must be *sound*, i.e. $\bot$ (the *absurdity*) has no proof.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. Can you please take a look at the following problem when you have time? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547669/how-to-show-validity-of-a-skolem-formula-in-lk